# Data Protection of data is shared

Tags: data-storage

i am not sure if I posting in the correct place and i will delete if not.

I have been asked by my boss how long do we have to keep customer data for?

He is a retailer and fixes computers.
A customer will come in and book their PC in for repair.
The name and address of that customer is entered into the system.
It is saved locally on that PC BUT it is also copied and stored on a server supplied by another company.

How long does that company have to legally keep/save this data for?

thanks

Comment: It depends on the jurisdiction.  Where does the company operate?  Where does the other company operate?  Where are its servers?  Does it have mirrors in other jurisdictions?

Comment: @phoog thanks for posting,  The company is based in UK.  Their servers are based in England, There are no mirrors.  My question is based around the fact that it is a copy of data and that the master data is stored with us. So, mirrors would not come into it.  It is an issue of the master and the copy and whether the copy versions have the same legality as if it was the only repository of the data